# How can i delete a row from 2D ndarray if the row contains at least one 0

Tags: python, pandas

let's say i have a dataset like this

| age | id | BMI | insulin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 0 | 30 | 0 |
| 11 | 30 | 17 | 30 |
| 27 | 15 | 30 | 0 |
| 5 | 21 | 30 | 45 |
| 0 | 21 | 30 | 45 |
| 21 | 21 | 0 | 45 |

now i want to delete the row that contains 0. I read all the data using panda now how can i delete these row from my dataset or after converting to a 2D array

Answer (score 1):

2 methods to achieve your goal:

```
# keep rows where all values != 0
df = df[df.ne(0).all(1)]

# or drop rows where at least one value == 0
df = df.drop(df[df.eq(0).any(1)].index)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   age  id  BMI  insulin
1   11  30   17       30
3    5  21   30       45
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter rows with no `0` values per rows by compare by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df = df[df.ne(0).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the dataset (I assume it's a list) and check to see if each item is 0. If it is not a zero you can add it to a new list ( a list with no 0s ). Example:

```
dataset = [age, id, BMI, insulin, 15, 0, 30, 0, 11, 30, 17, 30, 27, 15, 30, 0, 5, 21, 30, 45, 0, 21, 30, 45, 21, 21, 0, 45]

new_dataset = [] # new dataset which will only have values that are not zero

for data_point in dataset:
    if data_point != 0:
        new_dataset.append(data_point)
# our new dataset now contains all values from previous set without zeros
```